# phpmyadmin page not found on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin

i set up a my a localserver on my pc according to [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04#how-to-find-your-server-39-s-public-ip-address) tutorial, but my phpmydamin page doesn't shown, it just says error 404 not found. I have followed plenty of guides but the problems keep exists, what can i do?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

did the MySQL-server and Apache2 run properly?? 
open the terminal to check it and then type this command :

```
Sudo systemctl status apache2.service
```

and for mysql :

```
Sudo systemctl status mysql.service
```

did you have been installed phpmyadmin?? on the link what you post on the question it just configure Apache2,MySQL and PHP.. but not Phpmyadmin.

Comment: thank you for your answer, yes the apache, mysql was running properly and php myadmin was also installed, but now i purged everything and i installed xampp. Thank you again.

Comment: youre wellcome . dont forget to make the question solved :)